# Conjectures mentioned (and proposed) at International Congresses of Mathematics

Tags: mathematics

I guess that every International Congress of Mathematics (Mathematicians) brings up some unresolved issues of various types but that also that at least some (if not all) ICM´s present some new unsolved problems (conjectures).

Is there some comprehensive monograph (or handbook) about almost all the open problems (conjectures) mentioned (and proposed) at all the ICM´s?

Comment: No, there is no such a monograph.

Comment: The problem with this is that probably 95% (maybe over 99%) of the conjectures that might be made (unless restricted to those made in a Plenary address) are probably extremely specialized and technical, and would be understandable to only a very few people. For instance, I could easily rattle off a bunch of conjectures in certain esoteric areas of classical real analysis I know something about that would likely have no meaning or interest to you.